# ANDROID: What version of Google Play Services am I using?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Basically title. In my code gradle, the website here:http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html tells me to put this in the gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

However, this is not a working solution to my app. I get the error:
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            GridGame:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Ryan Folz/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            GridGame:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0

I have no idea where to start in terms of what to do here.

Any help would be wonderful :)

Comment: Looks like it's telling you you're missing the support libraries. Their docs say to add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' before the compile statement you listed.

Comment: @Guardanis how would i go about installing them?

Comment: Just add the line I included (which was taken directly from the documentation page you linked to) before the line you entered that starts with the word 'compile'

Comment: update your support library maven repositories via android SDK manager. the play services 7.0.0 need support-v4:22.0.0 which is currently not installed. youll also need to raise build tools, target sdk and compile sdk to 22.

Comment: update your support library

Answer (score 0):

You can check what versions you have installed by going to this path: `%appdata%\..\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services` and checking what version folders are there.